# How can we retrieve variable from invocation.module_args when we register some data?

Tags: ansible

When I do this:

```
- name: get snapshot

  vmware_guest_snapshot_facts:

     hostname: "{{ fe_rhel_maj_template_vw__vc_drv }}"

     username: "{{ vcenter_ad_rw.username }}"

     password: "{{ vcenter_ad_rw.password }}"

     datacenter: "{{ fe_rhel_maj_template_vw__cluster_drv }}"

     folder: "{{ fe_rhel_maj_template_vw__cluster_drv }}"

     name: lphost

  register: snapshot_facts_lin_win
```

I retrieve this:

```
{

    "_ansible_parsed": true,

    "invocation": {

        "module_args": {

            "username": "xxx@xxx.xxx",

            "datacenter": "xxx",

            "name": "lphost",

            "hostname": "xxxfff@xxx.xxx",

            "folder": "yyyyyy",

            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",

            "validate_certs": true,

            "port": 443,

            "uuid": null

        }

    },

    "changed": false,

    "_ansible_no_log": false,

    "guest_snapshots": {

        "current_snapshot": {

            "id": 1,

            "state": "poweredOff",

            "creation_time": "2018-11-06T14:39:40.431223+00:00",

            "description": "",

            "name": "Pré-CIS"

        },

        "snapshots": [

            {

                "id": 1,

                "state": "poweredOff",

                "creation_time": "2018-11-06T14:39:40.431223+00:00",

                "description": "",

                "name": "Pré-CIS"

            }

        ]

    }

}
```

I am able to retrieve data from `guest_snapshots` structure but not from `invocation` structure...

Is there any way to retrieve and match `guest_snapshots` and `invocation`, especially the `invocation.module_args.name`?

Comment: What have you tried? What errors do you get? Please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

No. `invocation` is an internal field and it is stripped out of registered result by Ansible.

Otherwise it can be used to steal sensitive data like passwords.